# Save Column Option settings in TFS?

Tags: tfs

Is there any way to save your Column Option settings so that you can re-use them or apply them to other queries in TFS?

I've searched and it doesn't appear there is a way to do this, but maybe I am missing something.

Comment: What columns?  A work item query result?  In VS or in the browser?

Comment: Oh - Work item query result. Visual Studio.

Comment: You could edit the WIQL and copy and paste it around, but I can't thing of anything more elegant.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.. Follow below steps

1. Create a Query under queries pane. Make sure it works & Results are displayed
2. Now customise the view by clicking on the 'Column Options' & remove or add any column by DOUBLE CLICKING on it option followed by OK to save for current view
3. From the Result screen, notice 'SAVE QUERY' option. This should save your current view as it is to the Query

Voila.. Your view is saved as it is in the Query

Comment: This works for individuals, but is there a way to ensure that these settings are persisted for the Query itself so that all users end up with the same view?